# mkdir throws 'unknown option' error

Tags: bash, sh

I have a problem with `mkdir` command.
When I run `mkdir -p "-AFolder"`, I am getting the following error:

```
mkdir: unknown option -- A
```

What's is causing the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mkdir` command tries to interpret "-AFolder/" as an option as it begins with a `-`.

Use the `--` dummy argument to tell explicitly that you are not providing an option :

```
mkdir -- -AFolder
```

From the Bash manpage:

> Unless  otherwise  noted,  each builtin command documented in this
>   section as accepting options preceded by - accepts -- to signify the
>   end of the options.

Answer (score 2):

```
mkdir -p  -- "-AFolder"
```

Use `--` to tell the bash command that anything that follows is not a flag, its a part of the argument. From man bage:

> --        A -- signals the end of options and disables further option
>   processing.  Any arguments after the -- are treated as filenames and
>   argu-
>                    ments.  An argument of - is equivalent to --.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `--` convention that `mkdir` supports, you can also prepend the directory name with `./`.

```
mkdir ./-AFolder
```